# 'Position: bottom' not working on relatively positioned button element

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

*Goal*: Get the `button` element fixed to the bottom of the `main` element. I tried positioning it's container with relative positioning so it sticks to the bottom:

```
/* POSITIONING NOT WORKING. I WANT THIS DIV FIXED TO BOTTOM OF PARENT */
.wrapper:nth-child( 4 ) {
  background-color: #bbb;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This isn't moving the `.wrapper` div at all. Ideas?

```css
@import url( "https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" );
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  background-color: #eee;
}
main, input {
  padding: 2%;
}
main input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5% 0;
  border: 0;
}
.clr-fix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  float: left;
}

/* POSITIONING NOT WORKING. I WANT THIS DIV FIXED TO BOTTOM OF PARENT */
.wrapper:nth-child( 4 ) {
  background-color: #bbb;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="clr-fix">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" value="position:bottom">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text" value="Isn't working">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text" value="On 'A button'">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <button>A button</button>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Relative positioning is a change in relation to the spot the element is already positioned. So if position: relative, bottom: 0 (or top:0, left:0, right:0, etc) means leave this at the same spot it currently is.

If you want this positioned to the bottom of the element, you need to make the parent element position: relative, and the element you want pinned to the bottom position: absolute (with bottom: 0). Absolutely positioned elements will hop on out of the DOM flow and go instead in relation to it's closest relative parent.

essentially you want:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:nth-child(4){
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that though this moves my element to the bottom. it is pushed to the far left by default once it is absolutely positioned. A `left` or `right` value can be used to move the element back to its horizontal position as shown in @Novocent's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your main style will need a relative position applied to it. As mentioned, you can't position `bottom:0` with relative positioning. See if this works for you.

```
main{
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #bbb;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
  right: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the 4'th wrapper stick to bottom you need to put `position: relative;` on `main` and add `position: absolute` to the 4'th wrapper.

a `position: absolute;` element is absolutely positioned relatively to it's closest parent which is `position: relative;` - in your case that would be `main` which wraps the 4'th wrapper.